# SQL Server 2008 - Different ways of sending an email and dependencies

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, notifications, database-mail

What are all the different ways (in code and from the GUI) which SQL Server 2008 can be used to send emails? For each way please state any dependencies e.g. an Outlook profile or Database Mail (enabled and configured).

So far I know of the following ways:

- sp_send_dbmail (code) which requires Database Mail to be enabled and configured
- Operator Properties - Notification options (GUI) which depends on ???
- Alert - Response - Notify operators (GUI) which depends on ???
- Job - Notifications - job complete (GUI) which depends on ???
- Maintenance Plan - Notify Operator Task (GUI) which depends on ???

Are the any other ways in which SQL Server can be used to send an email either in code or through the GUI? I am only interested in the simple methods - preferably nothing complicated.

I am asking because I am confused by the array of different methods of doing the same thing, and I'm not confident in testing them out without knowing what the preliminary steps are!

I will accept the best answer which fills in the gaps in my knowledge and also provides a concise yet complete listing of all the different (simple) methods.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "Database Mail" is the email subsystem in SQL Server that replaces SQLMail+MAPI, so they all depend on Database Mail

Comment: Ok thanks - I wasn't sure about whether any of the options used an Outlook profile of something. So Database Mail definitely needs to be enabled and configured before I can do anything regarding emails?

Comment: The older horrible mail system used MAPI, Database Mail uses vanilla SMTP so is much simpler, you need to configure it as its what manages the different profiles (mail server address/credentials etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all of the ways rely on [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx), which in the end uses the sp_send_dbmail procedure like this:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail    
    @recipients = 'you@email.com',
    @body = 'Body Message',
    @subject = 'Subject' ;
```

You will need to create a profile before sending any email. [Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/) is a link to help

Database Mail doesn't depend on  Outlook or MAPI anymore, it uses SMTP to send mail

Comment: So sp_notify_operator uses sp_send_dbmail ?

Comment: yes it does. If you see the proc code, you'll see the call to sp_send_dbmail on line 64

Comment: Where can I see the source of that SP in SQL Server 2008 - I can't find it!

Comment: Ok thanks. I have enabled and configured Database Mail and tested it and it works great. I now wish to create a job, where one of the steps is to execute sp_send_dbmail. Would you be able to tell me if I can run the job from an insert trigger without the trigger blocking?

Comment: glad to help, please remember to vote and mark as answer if it helped you. Well, you can use the proc  sp_start_job to run the job but why do you need the job? Why not call the send_mail procedure. Nevertheless, I dont think that calling both a job or sending an email is a good practice from inside a trigger. If you really need this behavior why not, inside the trigger, insert a record on a auxiliary table and have a job that reads from this table every 5 minutes and send the email?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9733/discussion-between-chris-cannon-and-diego)